# Получается не верный ответ, что я сделал не так?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
*       Найти сумму всех кратных 3 или 5 ниже 1000.
*/
void main()
{

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
    {

        if (i%3==0)
        {
            a = a + i;

        }
        if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            b = b + i;
        }

    }

    cout << a + b << endl;
}
```

Comment: Вы, наверное, не учитываете числа, что кратные и 5, и 3 одновременно, поэтому они суммируются дважды

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Циклы не нужны, так как тут считается сумма арифметической прогрессии. Чтобы не учитывать числа, кратные обоим данным числам, по два раза, из итоговой суммы следует вычесть сумму чисел, кратных их произведению.

```
#include <iostream>

static auto asum(auto const step, auto const limit)
{
    auto const n{(limit - 1) / step};
    return (step * n * (n + 1)) / 2;
}

int main()
{
    auto const limit{1000};
    auto const a{3};
    auto const b{5};
    auto const sum{asum(a, limit) + asum(b, limit) - asum(a * b, limit)};
    ::std::cout << sum << ::std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/fbPrHm)

Comment: Вот что интересно, если limit будет не 1000, а побольше, то `auto` с 32 на 64-bit перейдет?

Comment: @avp Если это вопрос про конструкцию `auto const limit{1000};`, то да, перейдет. С другой стороны, при таких больших числах все равно будет переполнение при умножении.

Comment: Да, вопрос неточно сформулирован. Я имел в виду, конечно, автоматический переход к 64-bit в `auto const n` внутри `asum()` и далее `auto const sum`

Comment: Пока еще стандарт широко не поддерживается, с возможностями С++20, как мне кажется, перебор...

Comment: @avp Нет, там auto никак не повлияет.

Comment: @Mikhailo Ну из возможностей C++ 20 тут разве что auto в параметре функции. Но можно начинать привыкать уже сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
    sum += i;
}
console.log(sum);
```

```js
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 3; i < 1000; i += 3) {
    sum += i;
}
for (var i = 5; i < 1000; i += 5) {
    sum += i;
}
for (var i = 15; i < 1000; i += 15) {
    sum -= i;
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если число  `i` не делится на `5`, то  `i * 3` не будет делиться на 5. Исходя из этого, можно написать следующее:

```
int sum = 0;        
for (int i = 1; i <= 333; ++i) {
    if (i % 5)
        sum += i * 3;
    if(i < 200)
        sum += i * 5;        
}
std::cout << sum;
```

Таким образом сокращается цикл в три раза: